# Create table from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have two tables (A,B) inside my database.
Now I will create a new Table C which is from the columns identical to the table B.I want to write all the data from table B which geometry is inside table A in the new table C!

something like:

```
CREATE TABLE "C" (ID2 serial PRIMARY KEY, "geom" geometry, "id" bigint, "Name" varchar, "Feature" int, "ID2" bigint, "Code_1" varchar, "Wert_1" varchar, "Code_2" varchar, "Wert_2" int);

INSERT INTO C (geom)

SELECT ST_Intersection (A.geom, B.geom)

From A, B
```

The result is a table with the geometry after the intersection.
Furthermore I need the rest of the data too (id, name...)

Comment: `CREATE TABLE tableC as SELECT ....`

Answer (score 2):

Another option is:

```
CREATE TABLE tableC (LIKE tableB INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO tableC 
SELECT b.* FROM tableB b
  JOIN tableA ON NOT ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection (A.geom, B.geom));
```

That will create all indexes and keys for you.

Comment: nice, didnt knew that one,

Comment: `LIKE ... INCLUDING ALL` is a nice way around the fact that indexes are not propagated with `INHERITS` too.

Comment: I got an error message argument Join/ON must be type boolean and not geometry. How can I solve this issue?

Comment: fixed.  intersection returns an empty geometry if no intersection.  So us ST_IsEmpty.

Comment: sorry I have found a mistake in my result. The geometry is not correct. In table a Ihave the geometry for few areas. And at the moment I need tableA.id = 2 for the intersection. I can add this inside a where clause after the Join right? but the result geometry (I see the layer in QGIS) is not limited on this area

Comment: use the boolean function `ST_Intersects`

Answer (score 1):

use the boolean function `ST_Intersects`

```
 CREATE TABLE tableC AS
      SELECT tableB.*, -- (all field less geom)
             ST_Intersection (A.geom, B.geom) as geom   -- generate geom
      FROM tableA
      JOIN tableB
        ON ST_Intersects (A.geom, B.geom)   -- boolean function
```

After that remember you need create index and constrains like PK or FK.

Comment: no this is not working (error message) because after Join/On the type has to be boolean and I have geometry

Comment: this is the query: `CREATE TABLE C (LIKE eingangsdaten INCLUDING ALL);
INSERT INTO C
SELECT b.* FROM table b
  JOIN table a ON NOT ST_IsEmpty(ST_Intersection (a.geom, b.geom))
  WHERE a.id = 2;` but the result is not correct

Comment: So you want insert the intersection?

Comment: yes. In the new table I will only have the geometry of the intersection and the regarding columns

Comment: check the update... Im in phone so cant update the field list. But I think you can do that?

Comment: it occurs a syntax error _LINE 3:      ST_Intersection (a.geom, b.geom) as geom_ something with the brackets !

Comment: this is working: ` CREATE TABLE tableC AS
     (SELECT --tableB.*
     ST_Intersection (A.geom, B.geom) as geom  -- generate geom
     FROM tableA
     JOIN tableB
     ON ST_Intersects (A.geom, B.geom)
     WHERE test.id = 2);` . But then I have only geometry. If I uncoment SELECT --tableB an error occurs

Comment: Dont post code in comment, the format make it unreadable. Instead edit your question with that aditional info. Also please include the error message.

Comment: You realize was a missing `coma` between tableB.* and ST_Interesection?